# How do I convert a sequence of sequences into a sequence of maps with clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm reading data from a file where each line has two values. Each line is represented by a sequence within an outer sequence representing the file.

I'd like to restructure the data into a sequence of maps for further processing.

I know how to create a map from a key set and sequence of values:

```
=> (defstruct entry :name :age)
=> (apply struct entry '("John" 34))
{:name "John", :age 34}
```

But how do I create a sequence of such maps based on a sequence of value sequences?

```
(map (apply struct entry) '(("John" 34) ("Lisa" 41))))
```

results in:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.PersistentStructMap$Def
```

EDIT: Renamed symbol for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

structs are obsolete, the preference is to use records now.

```
(defrecord Person [name age])

(map (partial apply ->Person) '(("John" 34) ("Lisa" 41)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `zipmap`

```
(map (partial zipmap [:name :age]) '(("John" 34) ("Lisa" 41)))

;-> ({:name "John", :age 34} {:name "Lisa", :age 5})
```